# Why doesn't possessive "his" have distinct forms like "her" vs. "hers"?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-gender

I'm trying to understand why there is a difference between the possessive determiner and pronoun for the female gender (*her* vs *hers*) but not for the male gender (*his* is used for both).

"This will be discussed with him and **his** parents will be informed" and "This will be discussed with her and **her** parents will be informed" both seem correct, but I'm wondering about the origin of the fact that 'male' gender does not have a distinction whereas the female gender appears to have one, e.g. we would not say "**hers** parents".

Is there an etymological reason for not using "hers parents", or just a stylistic one (e.g. "hers parents" sounds odd whereas "his parents" doesn't)?

Comment: Please ask at https://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do not ask on ell.stackexchange.com. They will close it, too. The difference between *her* and *hers* can be looked up in any dictionary of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Reg, and I have, not really phrased the question well, I was wondering about the origin of the difference between the genders...

Comment: I don't think this is grist for ELL. It appears to be more of a linguistic history question for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used as an adjective in front of a noun (like "parents"), we use a possessive *determiner* ("his" or "her"). When used in place of the noun, we use a possessive *pronoun* ("his" or "hers") ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc)).

> I talked to her (*determiner*) parents, but I did not talk to his (*pronoun*).
>   *c.f.*
>   I talked to his (*determiner*) parents, but I did not talk to hers (*pronoun*).

Comment: Thanks, I was more wondering why the two (possessive determiner and pronoun) are different for the female gender and if there was an etymological reason to do with it, or just a stylistic one. e.g. "hers parents" sounds odd whereas "his parents" doesn't.

Comment: I could quote the entries on https://www.etymonline.com for "his," "her," and "hers," but you can probably just read them for yourself. As others have commented, if you still have questions after doing that bit of reading, it's proper on this site to post with clear questions and to state what research you have already done.